# Why do I need to add DOTALL to python regular expression to match new line in raw string

Tags: python, regex

Why does one need to add the DOTALL flag for the python regular expression to match characters including the new line character in a raw string. I ask because a raw string is supposed to ignore the escape of special characters such as the new line character. From the docs:

**The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline.**

This is my situation:

```
string = '\nSubject sentence is:  Appropriate support for families of children diagnosed with hearing impairment\nCausal Verb is :  may have\npredicate sentence is:  a direct impact on the success of early hearing detection and intervention programs in reducing the negative effects of permanent hearing loss'

re.search(r"Subject sentence is:(.*)Causal Verb is :(.*)predicate sentence is:(.*)", string ,re.DOTALL)
```

results in a match , However , when I remove the DOTALL flag, I get no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source string is **not** raw, only your pattern string.

maybe try

```
string = r'\n...\n'
re.search("Subject sentence is:(.*)Causal Verb is :(.*)predicate sentence is:(.*)", string)
```

Answer (score 2):

In regex `.` means `any character except \n`

So if you have newlines in your string, then `.*` will not pass that newline(`\n`).

But in Python, if you use the [re.DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag(also known as `re.S`) then it includes the `\n`(newline) with that dot `.`